# How to setup comment-start and comment-start-skip?

Tags: comment

Haskell has line comments starting with `--` and multiline comments of the form `{- ... -}`. I'd like to make auto-fill-mode work for both of those.

Currently line comments are auto-filled correctly:

```
-- abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc 
-- abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

but multiline comments are not:

```
{- abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc 
{- abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

it should be just with spaces:

```
{- abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc 
   abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

current settings are:

```
(set (make-local-variable 'comment-start) "-- ")
(set (make-local-variable 'comment-padding) 0)
(set (make-local-variable 'comment-start-skip) "[-{]-[ \t]*")
(set (make-local-variable 'comment-end) "")
(set (make-local-variable 'comment-end-skip) "[ \t]*\\(-}\\|\\s>\\)")
```

How to set this up so that comment auto-fill works for both kinds of comments?

More about Haskell Mode: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode

Comment: You should look at the `adaptive-fill-function`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not clear how this should work but at least I have a clue where to look next.